# phpstorm開発環境について

Tags: centos, windows-10, phpstorm

現在virtualbox＋vagrant＋centos7という構成で
ローカルpc（Windows10上）に開発環境を構築し
apacheを立てwordpressを管理しています。

今回phpstormを導入しようと考えていたのですが
centos上にインストールするのはあまり一般的ではないのでしょうか？
というのも色々検索をかけてもubuntuにインストールする情報は出てくるのですが
centosにインストールする情報はほとんどなく
Windowsにインストールしてそこからリモートで管理する情報も多かったため
質問させていただいている状況です。
似たような環境のご経験談など伺えましたら嬉しいです。

また調べているうちに以下のような疑問も出てきて皆様のご意見を伺いたいと思いました。
centosは現在puttyでアクセスし、viやatomで編集などを
おこなっていますがphpstormをcentosで動かす際は
centosをguiモードで立ち上げておく必要があるのでしょうか？
それともターミナル（putty）からphpstormだけ起動する
というようなことは可能なのでしょうか。

またWindows上でphpstormを立ち上げvirtualboxのcentos内にリモートする場合と比べて
メモリ、cpuの負担はどちらが少ないでしょうか。
自分としてはcentos内で完結した方がphp、apache、centosなどの環境も
本番と統一でき、cpu、メモリなどの負担も少なそうな感じがしたので
centosにインストールする手順を調べたのですが
この辺りも認証の間違いなどあれば突っ込んでいただければ幸いです。
長乱文失礼いたしました。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

> centosをguiモードで立ち上げておく必要があるのでしょうか？

**必要です。**

> centos上にインストールするのはあまり一般的ではないのでしょうか？

普通の使い方です。install-linux-tar.txtの通りにすれば動きます。

> またWindows上でphpstormを立ち上げvirtualboxのcentos内にリモートする場合と比べて
>   メモリ、cpuの負担はどちらが少ないでしょうか。

virtualboxが動いているので、どちらにインストールしても重たくなると思いますが、Windowsにインストールする方が良いと私は思います。
(pcにcentosを直接インストールして開発環境を構築する事をおすすめします。)

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはりguiは必要になるんですね。linuxについても知識が浅く、できることとできないことを調べるのが難しかったので助かりました。windowsでのセッティングを考えてみます！

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 上に PhpStorm をインストールするのは一般的ではないように思います。
Ubuntu はあくまで普段使いのホスト OS のデスクトップ環境としての事例が見つかっているのではないでしょうか。

RNeJRHXaFXmjY さんはいわゆるローカル開発環境を Vagrant で構築している状態かと思いますが、通常ローカル開発環境を利用したコーディング環境の主なパターンは以下のような感じでしょうか。

1. ローカル PC (物理 PC のホスト OS) に XAMPP などのアプリケーションを直接インストールして IDE でコーディング
2. 仮想環境にソースを都度アップロードしながらローカル PC で IDE (保存時に自動アップロードしてくれる機能が IDE に実装されていることが多い)
3. 共有フォルダ設定により仮想環境とローカル PC のソースを同期してローカル PC で IDE

仮想環境にデスクトップ環境を用意してその中で IDE でコーディングというのはなかなかアクロバティックな印象ですが、恐らくオーバーヘッドがあるのでメモリやCPUなどのリソースを余計に食ってしまい、特にマウス操作でもっさり感も出てストレスを感じるのではないかと思います。

[Using Intellij as Remote X Windows App - Ilya Kazakevich - Confluence](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/~link/Using+Intellij+as+Remote+X+Windows+App)
こんな方法もあるかもしれません。実際に試してはいませんが、MobaXterm あたりを使うといいんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。いろいろなパターンをご教授いただき非常に参考になりました。現状2の運用に近いのですが、２，３を検討してwindowsベースで考えてみたいと思います。centosのguiで少し動かしてみたんですがやはり無理があるのかおっしゃる通りもっさりした動きになりました。centosをホストOSにするのがいいのかもしれません。参考になりましたm(_)mありがとうございました！